# JavaEE 6: @EJB(beanInterface="")

Tags: annotations, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

Could someone help me understand the use of `beanInterface` parameter of `@EJB` annotation in JavaEE 6?

I have a situation in which I have an EJB and I want it to be accessed locally and remotely as well.

I have a `MyBaseInterface` and then both `MyEJBLocalInterface` and `MyEJBRemoteInterface` extending `MyBaseInterface`. Now I have `MyEJB` which is implementing both `MyEJBLocalInterface` and `MyEJBRemoteInterface`.

Now I have a situation in which I want only to access `MyEJB` locally.

Could I achieve the same with the following?

```
@EJB(beanInterface=MyEJBLocalInterface.class)
private MyBaseInterface instanceOfLocallyAccessedMyEJB;
```

Could someone help me understand the use of `beanInterface` parameter of `@EJB` attribute?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the beanInterface attribute of the @EJB annotation is used for different purposes depending on the EJB version you are using:

- In EJB 3.X you can use it to specify whether you want to use the remote of local reference of the EJB you are referring to, which is your case.
- In EJB 2.X it is used to specify the Home/LocalHome interface of the session/entity bean

To sum up, yes. You should be able to use it to inject the desired interface.

This might not be supported in older versions of JBoss though.

Comment: Do you know if jboss 6 supports '@EJB'